# How to use Mongodb in Server Side Rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

### I am trying to make a basic mongoose connection in Express using React, React Router and webpack

### Are there any examples of ssr with Mongodb?

What should the server look like?

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("./build"));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
      const url = req.originalUrl || req.url;
      const context = {};
      const indexFile = path.resolve("./build/main.html");
      if (context.url) {
            req.header("Location", context.url);
            return res.send(302);
      }
      const css = new Set();
      const insertCss = (...styles) =>
            styles.forEach((style) => css.add(style._getCss()));
      const appContent = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <StyleContext.Provider value={{ insertCss }}>
                  <StaticRouter
                        location={req.url}
                        context={context}
                  ></StaticRouter>
            </StyleContext.Provider>
      );
      fs.readFile(indexFile, "utf8", (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return res.status(500).send("ne rabotaet");
            }
            data = data.replace("__STYLES__", [...css].join(""));
            data = data.replace(
                  "<div id=app></div>",
                  `<div id=app>${appContent}</div>`
            );

            return res.send(data);
      });
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("Listenning on port: ", 3000);
});
```

Comment: Hello! The code that has been added to the question currently doesn't have any reference to mongoose? Can you please update the question with snippets that you might have tried to establish a mongo connection.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below server template which is used for Next Js project (SSR) with Mongoose connection.
**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
    
    const express = require('express');
    const server = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const next = require('next');
    
    const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
    const app = next({dev});
    
    const routes = require('./routes');
    const routerHandler = routes.getRequestHandler(app);
    
    const {config} = require('../config');
    
    const transactionRouter = require('./api/transaction');
    
    app.prepare().then(() => {
        // Parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
        // Parse application/json
        server.use(bodyParser.json());
    
        // Allows for cross origin domain request:
        server.use(function (req, res, next) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
            next()
        });
        console.log("mongodb ", config.databaseUrl);
        // MongoDB
        mongoose.Promise = Promise;
        mongoose.connect(config.databaseUrl, {useNewUrlParser: true});
        const db = mongoose.connection;
        db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    
        // REST API routes
        server.use('/api/transactions', transactionRouter);
    
        // Next.js page routes
        server.get('*', routerHandler);
    
        // Start server
        server.listen(config.serverPort, () => console.log(`${config.appName} running on http://localhost:${config.serverPort}/`))
    });
```